# C# UWP set Tabpage backgroundcolor

Tags: c#, uwp, tabs, uwp-xaml

I've created a Tabpage on a Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls Tabcontrol like this:

```
        muxc.TabViewItem TabPage = new muxc.TabViewItem();
        TabPage.Name = "MyTab";
        TabPage.Header = "Title.txt";
        TabPage.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0));
        MyTabControl.TabItems.Add(TabPage);
```

So now I tried to change the backgroundcolor of the Tabpage:

```
        TabPage.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0));
```

But the tabpage backgroundcolor hasn't changed.
Does anyone know what i did wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to change the brush value that the TabView Item used.
Like this:

```
        <muxc:TabView.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabViewItemHeaderBackground" Color="LightGreen"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabViewItemHeaderForeground" Color="Blue"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </muxc:TabView.Resources>
```

Or in another way, you might need to create your customized TabView style based on the default style. You could find the default TabView style here on Github: [TabView.xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/1b66f00eafd0b18832738fb05ad064202c200115/dev/TabView/TabView.xaml)

Comment: Can I also change the color of each tabpage individually?